# Optimal scheduling system in terms of lowest waiting time for users and maximum users in waiting intervals

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I'm trying to look for an algorithm to optimally schedule events, given a set of timeslots. Each event (a,b) is a meeting between 2 users and each timeslot is a fixed amount of time.
eg. a possible set of events can be: [(1,2),(1,3),(4,2),(4,3),(3,1)] with 4 possible timeslots. All events have to be scheduled in a certain timeslot, however, waiting time per user should be minimised (time between two events) and at the same time, the amount of users in a waiting timeslot should be maximised.

Do you know of any possible algorithm or heuristic for this problem?

Greetings

Comment: Are the timeslots of equal length? Also, should overall waiting time be minimised, or only waiting time between two events? Is free time at the end(when no more events are left for the user) also waiting time?

Comment: Are multiple meetings allowed to happen in parallel?  i.e. (1,2) and (4,3) in the first timeslot, (1,3) and (4,2) in the 2nd timeslot, then users 1 and 3 exchange seats and have the (3,1) meeting in the 3rd timeslot.  I assume duplicate or reversed-order meetings are still supposed to happen?

Comment: This makes me think of CPU instruction schedulers that look ahead in the instruction stream for independent instructions that can run in parallel.  That won't give you any global optimization of scheduling a user's meetings all in a short block, though.

Comment: Timeslots are of equal length. Preferably waiting time between two events needs to be minimised. Free time at the end is not considered as waiting time. The ideal situation for each user is that every meeting happens after each other. However, if a gap is required, the amount of people waiting at the same time should be maximised. As such, people waiting can converse with a maximum amount of other people. Events can be organised in paralell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a maybe-better-than-random solution with a simple approach:

1. sort each pair with the lower-numbered user first
2. sort the list on first-user (primary key), second-user (secondary sort key)
3. schedule meetings in that order, with any independent meetings scheduled in parallel.  (Like a CPU instruction scheduler looking ahead for independent instructions.  Any given user will still have their meetings in the listed order.  You're just finding allowed overlaps here.)

---

I'm unfortunately not an expert on trying to reduce problems to known NP problems like the travelling salesman problem.  It's possible there's a polynomial-time solution to this, but it's not obvious to me.  If nobody comes up with one, then read on:

If the list isn't too big, you could brute-force check every permutation.  For each permutation, schedule all the meetings (with independent meetings in parallel), then sum the last-first meeting times for every user.  That's the score for that permutation.  Take the permutation with the lowest score.

---

Instead of brute force, you could use a random start point and evolve towards a local minimum.  Phylogenetics software [like phyml](http://www.atgc-montpellier.fr/download/papers/phyml_2010.pdf) uses this technique to search for maximum-likelihood evolutionary tree, which has a similarly factorial search space.

1. Start with a random permutation and evaluate its score
2. make some random changes, then evaluate the score
3. if it's not an improvement, try another permutation until you find one that is.  (maybe with a mechanism to remember that you already tried this modification to the starting tree).
4. **Repeat from 2** with this new tree, until you've converged on a local minimum.
5. **Repeat from 1** for some other starting guesses, and take the best final result.

If you can efficiently figure out the score change from a swap, that will be a big speedup over re-computing the score for a permutation from scratch.

---

This is similar to a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).  You should read up on that and see if any of those ideas can work.

Answer (score 2):

Sound like a combination of [**Job Shop Scheduling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c)) and **Meeting Scheduling** ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4meWIhPRVn8)) with a fairness constraint. Both are NP-complete.

Use a simple greedy Construction Heuristic (such as [First Fit Decreasing](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#firstFitDecreasing)) with Local Search (such as [Tabu Search](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#tabuSearch)). For these use cases, Local Search leads to better results than Genetic Algorithms, as well be more scalable (see research competitions for [proof](http://www.cs.qub.ac.uk/itc2007/)).

For the fairness constraint "waiting time per user should be minimised", penalize the waiting time *squared*:

[image]